# Data couldn't change to date format

Tags: date, google-sheets, time, format, converters

I am a beginner making formula. I have pull some data from several google sheet using QUERY+IMPORTRANGE which few column contain date. I can easily change the date to date using formatting feature. But only one column I couldn't change format to date. I've tried using

`=DATEVALUE` , `=TO_DATE`, `=DATE(mid, right, left)` but doesn't work

Examples of my data is as below (dd/mm/yy):

```
11.01.23
28.03.23
18.12.22
```

Please help me. tqvm

I've tried using =DATEVALUE , =TO_DATE, =DATE(mid, right, left) but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This should work-

```
=INDEX(DATE("20"&RIGHT(A1:A3,2),MID(A1:A3,4,2),LEFT(A1:A3,2)))
```

Basic formula for single cell `=DATE(2000+RIGHT(A1,2),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3; "."; "/")*1)
```

Comment: You might want to [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74939430/edit) some explanation to your code-only answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/33511202)